# Unable to use elements within iframe after switching

Tags: selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am using switching to an iframe using the below statements but on the final wait I get web element not found. Does anyone have any suggestions? I have trolled through google for about a day trying different techniques. None have worked so far

```
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
driver.switchTo().defaultContent()
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".b-iframe__iframe"))
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe)
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(
 'fieldset.radio-switch-group')))
```

Screen shot of HTML below image
[image: HTML]

Comment: You get `NoSuchElementException` or `TimeoutException`? post the stack trace.

Comment: Stack trace: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.cssSelector: fieldset.radio-switch-group (tried for 15 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:82)

Comment: If i put in explicit wait and perform driver.findElement then I get this exception Stack trace: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"PaymentPage"}. Its ike the switch statement isnt working

Comment: Can you share the code as copy past from your IDE?

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to locate the desired *WebElement* you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired frame to be available and switch to it.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be visible* and you can use either of the following solutions:

  - Using `cssSelector`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe.b-iframe__iframe[src*='securetest']")));
    WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("fieldset.radio-switch-group#balance-type")));
    ```
  - Using `xpath`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='b-iframe__iframe' and contains(@src,'securetest')]")));
    WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//fieldset[@class='radio-switch-group' and @id='balance-type']")));
    ```

Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: Thanks I've put that code in but with no luck. Its almost as if the switch isnt working. I have printed driver.pageSource and it is printing the entire DOM after the switch. I assumed that I should only get the iframe?

Comment: @JoeBatt Check if the `<iframe>` is nested within another `<iframe>` and update the question with your code trials and error stack trace.